Making all GitLab CI jobs manual by default
Is it possible to make all jobs in a GitLab CI pipeline manual, without adding rules: when: manual to all of them? I basically would like all jobs to have specific rules that trigger them, but in any case to be able to run them manually if I need.
I understand the possibility to use workflow: rules: to specify general rules, but, as far as I understand, these rules are applied to the whole pipeline, while I want to do so at the job level, so that I can manually trigger any job which did not run in a pipeline.
If it may be of help, in my pipeline definition, I have:
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # Tagged commit
      variables:
        ...
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH # Commit on main
      variables:
        ...
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true" # Commit on protected branch
      variables:
        ...
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never # Deactivate on-commit pipelines
    - when: always # Catch events like scheduled pipelines, merge request pipelines

I am using GitLab 17.5.

Adding the when: manual rule to all jobs is not feasible, as some jobs (which have several jobs depending on them) use !reference tags to import rules:
job1:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - somedir/**/*
    - when: manual

job2:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - *.txt
    - when: manual

job3:
  rules:
    - !reference [job1, rules]
    - !reference [job2, rules] # <-- will never be reached, because job1's `when: manual` prevents it


The only keyword that can do the inherit by default is default keyword which is not compatible with rules. But the example can be written in another format to be capable of this.
Solution 1: Using YAML-specific features like anchors (&), aliases (*), and map merging (<<).
job1:
  script:
    - echo "job 1"
  rules:
    - &rule_a
      changes:
        - somedir/**/*
    - when: manual

job2:
  script:
    - echo "job 2"
  rules:
    - &rule_b
      changes:
        - '*.txt'
    - when: manual

job3:
  script:
    - echo "job 3"
  rules:
    - *rule_a
    - *rule_b
    - when: manual

Solution 2: Using !reference
.common-rules:
  when-manual:
    - when: manual
.change-list-a:
  - somedir/**/*
.change-list-b:
  - '*.txt'

job1:
  script:
    - echo "job 1"
  rules:
    - changes: !reference [.change-list-a]
    - !reference [.common-rules, when-manual]

job2:
  script:
    - echo "job 2"
  rules:
    - changes: !reference [.change-list-b]
    - !reference [.common-rules, when-manual]

job3:
  script:
    - echo "job 3"
  rules:
    - changes: !reference [.change-list-a]
    - changes: !reference [.change-list-b]
    - !reference [.common-rules, when-manual]

